# rand() function does not work properly in C++

Tags: c++, search, random, binary

I am writing a game where the computer chooses a random number that a user has to guess. Then, It is the user to choose a number (he just guesses a number) that the computer has to guess. The problem is that the rand() function that i use in the second part of the game sometimes provides a number outside the new range. for instance if the new range is low=4 and high=10, rand() provides 12, which is not correct. I am trying to understand why that error, but i cannot find it. I am wrinting in Dev-C++. The code is right below followed by the output. Thanks for your help and time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>




using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int computer_guess, nbr, nbrguesses, count_user_guess=0, count_computer_guess=0; 
  char user_comparison;

  int  low=1, high=99;  //initialize low to the lower boundary and high to the higher     boundary

  srand(time(0));
  nbr=rand()% 99 + 1;  //computer chooses a random number between 1 and 99...

  do
  {
    cout << "guess a number now! " << endl;
    cin >> nbrguesses;     //user enters the number he guessed...
    if ( nbrguesses>nbr)
       cout << "too big" <<endl;
    else if ( nbrguesses<nbr)
       cout << "too small" << endl;
    else if ( nbrguesses==nbr)
       cout << " you found the correct number! " <<endl;

    count_user_guess++;  //count the number of guesses from the user
  }
  while (nbrguesses!=nbr);

  cout << "you tried " << count_user_guess <<" times to find the right number " <<      endl<<endl;

  cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
  cout << "Now, the computer will guess your number " << endl;

  do
  {
    srand(time(0));
    computer_guess=rand()% high + low;    //computer guesses the number
    cout << "computer guess: " << computer_guess <<endl;
    cout << "is it the correct number?" << endl;
    cin >> user_comparison;     //if user enter 
    if (user_comparison=='>')  // character '>' it means the number guessed by computer is too big
    {
       cout << "too big" <<endl;
       high= computer_guess-1;   //high is given a new boundary 
       cout << "***Current value of high = " << high << " and low = " << low << endl;    //display current boundaries

    }
    else if ( user_comparison=='<')  //the number guessed by computer is too small
    { 
      cout << "too small" << endl;
      low= computer_guess+1;  //low is given a new boundary
      cout << "***Current value of low = " << low << " and high = " << high << endl;  //display current boundaries

    }
    else if ( user_comparison=='=')
       cout << "Computer found the correct number! " <<endl;

    count_computer_guess++;  //count number of guesses from computer
  }
  while (user_comparison!='=');

  cout << "The computer tried " << count_computer_guess <<" times to find the right number " << endl;

  cout << "The Game is over now, have a good day!" << endl;
  getch();

  return 0; 

}

//**************Output******************************************

guess a number now!
50
too big
guess a number now!
25
you found the correct number!
you tried 2 times to find the right number

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Now, the computer will guess your number
computer guess: 11
is it the correct number?
>
too big
***Current value of high = 10 and low = 1
computer guess: 3
is it the correct number?
<
too small
***Current value of low = 4 and high = 10
computer guess: 12
is it the correct number?
```

Comment: That's **far** too much code for a Stack Overflow question!  If you believe the problem is to do with `rand`, then you should construct a short (i.e. < 10-line) test program to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: `rand` is certainly not the problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to replace

```
computer_guess=rand()% high + low;
```

by

```
computer_guess=rand()%(high- low + 1) + low;
```

In your example you have low = 4 and high = 10. But then you want a random number between 0 and 6 and add 4. Not one between 0 and 10, since then you could get results up to 14. If you dont want to include the high bound (Interval [low,high[ instead of [low,high] ) you have to omit the +1 in the brackets.

**Why**

rand() returns a pretty big integer number. And we want get a random number in the interval [a,b] from that.
If we take rand()%5, we get a numer which is 0,1,2,3 or 4, so from the interval [0,4]. In general rand()%C gives a random number in the interval [0,C-1].

If we add a constant number, e.g. Rand()%C + D, the interval is shifted: [D,C-1 +D].
So back to the problem, we want the interval to be [a,b]. Therefor we want a=D for the lower bond and C-1+D = b for the upper. This we can transform to C = b-D+1 = b-a+1.
So we want to use rand()%(b-a+1) + a.

Hope this explains a bit how things work.

Comment: I read that ( value % 100 + 1 ) is in the range 1 to 100. So, why should I use  computer_guess=rand()%(high- low) + low, instead of computer_guess=rand()% high + low? I thought that I was following the definition. Sorry, I am just trying to understand your solution.

Comment: It should actually be `rand() % (high-low+1) + low` if both, `low` and `high`, are to be included. The reason is that `x % m` has `m` possible values (when `x` and `m` are positive), and the range from `low` to `high` (inclusive) has `high - low + 1` elements.

Comment: It works, but I would really appreciate if i can have some explanations why (high-low)+low is the correct way to use rand() in my case. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great explanations,now I see where the problem was. Thank you so much to all of you for your time and help!

Comment: @DanielFischer I did meantion it in my post. But you are right I should change the code as well, since he asked for the closed interal.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close, but try this:

`rand()%(high-low)+low;`

Comment: It works with that solution. Is it possible to have more explanations why (high-low)+low, instead of high+low? Thanks!

Comment: @T4000 : Not to be rude but have you thought about it _at all_? Pretend to be `rand` and go through each number and see what the output of your function would be. It should be quite obvious.

Comment: @T4000, ildjarn's suggestion is pretty good, so do take step through that and see how it works. Let's also look at it anyway: `rand` gives you a number between 0 and a number greater than 32767. If your max is 10 and your min is 1, then 10-1 = 9 so the output of `rand % 9` would be a number between 0 and 9. Adding min to the rsult of `rand % 9` changes the range to be between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
srand(time(0));
computer_guess=rand()% high + low;    //computer guesses the number
```

First, don't call `srand` inside your loop. Just call it once when the program starts.

Second, that logic is wrong. It should be:

```
computer_guess=low + (rand() % (high-low+1));
```

(This assumes high and low are inclusive. That is, if high is 10 and low is 1, then both 1 and 10 are acceptable guesses.)

Comment: Avoid using the modulus operator `%` when using rand. The standard random number generator is an LCG, which produces very periodic end bits (the ones returned by `%`). Instead, truncate the last bits using integer division `/` to get the more random beginning bits.

Comment: @Seth : +1, agreed, or better yet use C++11/TR1's `<random>` or [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/libs/random/) for proper distributions.

Comment: @SethJohnson: Either way, you have pretty much no guarantees about the resulting distribution. If you care, you just shouldn't use `rand` because it doesn't make any guarantees.